# accessing papertrail api information with Python3 script

Tags: python, json, api

I have a PaperTrail account, and I am trying to write a Python script that accesses the PaperTrail logs and grabs the information as a JSON. This is my current attempt, and it's ugly -- I think I got fouled when trying to convert Python2 to Python3, and I have a somewhat unclear understanding of API/JSON as well.

```
import http.client, urllib, time, os, json

PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN = "[xxx]"

INTERVAL = 10 * 60

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host = 'papertrailapp.com')
conn.request(
    method = 'GET',
    url = '/api/v1/events/search.json'
    headers = {'X-Papertrail-Token' : os.environ['PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN']})
response = conn.getresponse()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some small changes to your program:

1. added a shebang line: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
2. added a `,` at the end of the `url` line to correct the syntax
3. pretty printed the JSON

`PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN = "[xxx]"` is not used - the program looks in the environment for this, so make sure to set that before running it: `export PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN=xxx`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import http.client, urllib, time, os, json

PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN = "[xxx]"

INTERVAL = 10 * 60

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host = 'papertrailapp.com')
conn.request(
    method = 'GET',
    url = '/api/v1/events/search.json',
    headers = {'X-Papertrail-Token' : os.environ['PAPERTRAIL_TOKEN']})
response = conn.getresponse()
print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.read()), indent=4))
```